# Bash function with only variables

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, scripting

I have two functions that only store variables. Example:

```
Function datanode1(){
    homedirectory = "/path/to/file"
    ConfigDirectory = "/path/to/file"
    user = "john"
    max_open_Files = 262114
}
```

`datanode2` is exactly the same, just different path files.

**I would like to do something like this:**

```
if [ "$a1" == "all" ]; then
    for i in [datanode2, datanode1] do
        *execute Script*
    done
fi
```

Is this possible? How are the functions acting as arrays?

Comment: Not `Function`, but `function`. and not **both** `function` and `()`. Just use `datanote1() { ...; }`

Comment: And not `var = value` but `var=value` -- see [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) and [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have functions named `datanode2` and `datanode1`, and you want to execute them in a loop, you could write like this:

```
for fun in datanode2 datanode1; do
    "$fun"
done
```

Btw the function definition in your example has some syntax error. It should be more like this:

```
datanode1() {
    homedirectory="/path/to/file"
    ConfigDirectory="/path/to/file"
    user="john"
    max_open_Files=262114
}
```